# Angular Material button click animation bug

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a pop up button when I click the button,pop up opening and i have 3 button there, first button always coming clicked animation.How do i cancel it.
Thanks for helping.

[popup button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AicMg.png),[other 3 button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey5dN.png)

HTML

```
<span style="color: darkgray">
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="getByDateAndPeriod(1,'day','gün')">Günlük</button>
</span>
<span style="color: darkgray">
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="getByDateAndPeriod(2,'month','ay')">Aylık</button>
</span>
<span style="color: darkgray">
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="getByDateAndPeriod(3,'quarter','çeyrek')" >Çeyreklik</button
</span>
```

Comment: please provide detail code including css as well.

Comment: css not writing anything,ts files ; i call function on constructor this.getByDateAndPeriod(2, 'month', 'ay');

Comment: I delete 1 of the buttons this time the other button is selected

Comment: Please create a full reproduction. Nobody can help with this description.

Comment: I added new images

Comment: If you're using Material's dialog component, set the [`autoFocus` configuration property](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig) to `false`.

Comment: @p4r1 i tryed and, const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
        dialogConfig.autoFocus = false; and error ' Property 'autoFocus' does not exist on type 'MatDialogConfig<any>'.'
i am using angular material 5.2.4

Comment: Open a dialog with configuration options like this: `this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, { autoFocus: false })`

Comment: The same as my problem ıf you click "Pick One" button pop up opening with clicked "ok" button
 [link] (https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

Comment: @p4r1 i tryed again but error : Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'autoFocus' does not exist in type 'MatDialogConfig<any>'
my package.json @angular/material": "5.0.0-rc0",

Comment: autoFocus correct method but my material release not supporting, ıf i can update material,lots of parts will not work.

Comment: Looks like that configuration option was added in 5.0.0-rc.1.